# Ошибка Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос

При выполнении запроса

```
 select
      AllYears.Year,
      count(FirstVisitYears.Patient) as Count
    from 

        (select
          min(extract(YEAR from ReceptionDate)) as Year,
          Patient
        from Receptions
        where
          ReceptionType like 'Первич%'
        group by
          Patient
      ) as FirstVisitYears right join 
        (
          select distinct
            extract(YEAR from ReceptionDate) as Year
          from Receptions
        ) as AllYears on 
        FirstVisitYears.Year = AllYears.Year
    group by
      AllYears.Year
```

Возвращается ошибка
Помогите разобраться:)

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
```

Пример работы [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/08a8c/13)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Он ругается на конструкцию `extract(YEAR from ReceptionDate)`. 
Замените ее на [YEAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186313%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)(ReceptionDate) в обеих местах и все будет нормально.

Пример [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/30a99/2)

Comment: Тогда не правильно работает запрос уже. в MySQL все верно он выдавал. Вывод должен быть 1 2 0 (по столбцам)

Comment: @ka6an4eg Поменял в примере фамилии написанные русским на транслит и все стало правильно. Я думаю, что sql fiddle просто схлопнул фамилии с одинаковым количеством символов т.к. он их не различил.

Comment: @Aplnvent да, уже разобрался) При создании таблицы указал имена в Юникоде (N'Иванова')

Comment: @Aplnvent а скажи пожалуйста, если в создании таблицы указать "declare Orders table" , то из-за чего ошибка при выполнении запроса ?

Comment: @ka6an4eg не совсем понял вопрос... При создании таблицы вообще нет ключевого слова `declare`. Что ты хотел получить этой конструкцией?

Comment: @Aplnvent ну если я хочу эту таблицу объявить как переменную типа table? т.е. напишу при создании таблицы" declare 'собака'Receptions table (..);  Insert into 'собака'Receptions....."  И затем выполню запрос

Comment: @ka6an4eg Вроде все верно объявляешь, можешь сделать пример на Sql Fiddle?

Comment: @Aplnvent  вот http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3488b

Comment: @ka6an4eg Код работоспособный. Но если ты будешь пытаться обращаться к табличной переменной из окна выполнения запроса в sqlfillder, то скорее всего ее уже не будет существовать. У нее очень ограниченая область действия - в рамках одного [batch](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175502(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: @Aplnvent понял,благодарю)